# Linking Ubuntu Documents to Windows Documents

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, symbolic-link

I would like to make my documents synchronised across my dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu system.

I've chosen to implement this as mounting the Windows data partition in Ubuntu at boot time with `fstab`, then making symlinks to my documents, pictures etc.

The question is, should I do a soft link (`ln -s ~/Documents /mnt/data/.../Documents`) or a hard link (`ln ~/Documents /mnt/data/.../Documents`)? I really can't decide!

Comment: Hard links don't even work! Linux will not allow you to make cross-drive hard links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a soft link, it is safer and I am not even sure that Windows can deal with Linux hard links, I don't know how NTFS deals with hard links.

However, do it the other way around. You want to link your Windows documents to your Linux `$HOME`:

1. First make sure that `/mnt/data/.../Documents` is up to date by copying any newer files from `~/Documents`:

   ```
   cp -ruv ~/Documents/* /mnt/data/.../Documents
   ```
2. Then delete the `~/Documents` directory (**make sure the step above worked first**) and create the link:

   ```
   rm -r ~/Documents 
   ln -s /mnt/data/.../Documents ~/Documents
   ```

That way Linux will simply treat the `/mnt/data/.../Documents` directory as its `~/Documents`. The whole process is transparent to Windows so you don't need to worry about file system compatibility issues.

Comment: Perfect! Yeah, I messed up my `ln` syntax, but that is what I meant! I went one further (as most directories have the same name Ubuntu <=> Windows) and removed my whole user directory, then linked it back again to my Windows user directory. Works great!

Comment: Woah! You now have a $HOME directory that is in NTFS format? This is not a good idea! You also just lost ALL your settings (directories and files starting with `.` that are not visible by default). If you have a backup I really really recommend that you switch back. If you want to, you can link specific directories as described in my answer but don't do the entire $HOME.