# Dual bootin windows and linux

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, debian

Hey firstly I don't know where to ask this question and I have not seen this type of question asked before. Although I have seen this question been asked here [Linking Ubuntu Documents to Windows Documents](https://superuser.com/questions/568010/linking-ubuntu-documents-to-windows-documents) but that's not what I am looking for. I currently dual boot windows and ubuntu. I have a 2tb hard drive installed on my pc and was wondering if it's a good idea to have all my files like documents, pictures, videos etc. except desktop, which I'll explain in a bit, on a single partition let's say 500GB and both windows and Debian, which I will install instead of ubuntu, on 750GB partitions. The reason why I don't want to have the desktop in the files partition is that the desktop is where all the application icons are held and I don't want to see a bunch of unknown icons in either os. Like I will still have a home folder where all the hidden folders are with local applications, not system-wide applications. I will probably symlink those folders in Debian and shortcut them in windows.

So, in the end, do you think this is a good idea or should I do it another way. 
Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: You can easily keep docs, images, videos, etc.on the Windows NTFS partition, which Linux can read. *Caveats:* 1. Don' use Fast Boot or Hibernation. 2. *Writing* to and NTFS partition from Linux can create issues... Windows is far worse handling ext4, though.

Comment: so is this a good idea or do you suggest another way to keep docs and videos the same

Comment: This forum is not for opinions... That said, I feel it's practical. An alternative is to use a file server, as simple as a Raspberry Pi and HDD.